# Effect of scaling Features when NaNs are set to -1

Tags: python, nan, scaling

I have a dataset containing some features with quite a lot of NaNs (up to 80%). Removing them, would skew my overall distribution, hence my options are to set all NaNs to -1/-99 or bin my continuous variable into groups, making it a categorical feature.

As I already have many categorical features, I'd rather not make the few continuous ones, categorical too. However, if I set NaNs to -1/-99 will that significantly affect results when I scale those features?

Or from a different perspective, is there a way of scaling features without having the -1 affect its scaling too much?

Comment: if *removing* them would change your overall distribution too much, how would *setting* them to an actual value not be much worse? That would skew your distribution heavily toward whatever value you choose.

Comment: Why not write a custom `TransformerMixin` that only fits the non-nan samples and then apply your -1/-99 imputation after that scaling?

Comment: @Zinki I should have been more clear. Everywhere with a NaN in col2 has a specific class for col1, hence removing NaNs leads to removing that class entirely.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 This is actually a really good idea. I will give it a go! Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you got the answer from the comments above, but in an effort to show new scikit-learn users how you might approach a problem like this, I've put together a very rudimentary solution that demonstrates how to build a custom transformer that would handle this:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_array, check_is_fitted
import numpy as np

class NanImputeScaler(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """Scale an array with missing values, then impute them
    with a dummy value. This prevents the imputed value from impacting
    the mean/standard deviation computation during scaling.

    Parameters
    ----------
    with_mean : bool, optional (default=True)
        Whether to center the variables.

    with_std : bool, optional (default=True)
        Whether to divide by the standard deviation.

    nan_level : int or float, optional (default=-99.)
        The value to impute over NaN values after scaling the other features.
    """
    def __init__(self, with_mean=True, with_std=True, nan_level=-99.):
        self.with_mean = with_mean
        self.with_std = with_std
        self.nan_level = nan_level

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # Check the input array, but don't force everything to be finite.
        # This also ensures the array is 2D
        X = check_array(X, force_all_finite=False, ensure_2d=True)

        # compute the statistics on the data irrespective of NaN values
        self.means_ = np.nanmean(X, axis=0)
        self.std_ = np.nanstd(X, axis=0)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        # Check that we have already fit this transformer
        check_is_fitted(self, "means_")

        # get a copy of X so we can change it in place
        X = check_array(X, force_all_finite=False, ensure_2d=True)

        # center if needed
        if self.with_mean:
            X -= self.means_
        # scale if needed
        if self.with_std:
            X /= self.std_

        # now fill in the missing values
        X[np.isnan(X)] = self.nan_level
        return X
```

The way this works is by computing the [`nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) and [`nanstd`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanstd.html) in the `fit` section so that the NaN values are ignored while computing the statistics. Then, in the `transform` section, after the variables are scaled and centered, the remaining NaN values are imputed with the value you designate (you mentioned -99, so that's what I defaulted to). You could always break that component of the transformer into another transformer, but I included it just for demonstration purposes.

#### Example in action:

Here we'll set up some data with NaNs present:

```
nan = np.nan
data = np.array([
    [ 1., nan,  3.],
    [ 2.,  3., nan],
    [nan,  4.,  5.],
    [ 4.,  5.,  6.]
])
```

And when we fit the scaler and examine the means/standard deviations, you can see that they did not account for the NaN values:

```
>>> imputer = NanImputeScaler().fit(data)
>>> imputer.means_
array([ 2.33333333,  4.        ,  4.66666667])
>>> imputer.std_
array([ 1.24721913,  0.81649658,  1.24721913])
```

Finally, when we transform the data, the data is scaled and the NaN values are handled:

```
>>> imputer.transform(data)
array([[ -1.06904497, -99.        ,  -1.33630621],
       [ -0.26726124,  -1.22474487, -99.        ],
       [-99.        ,   0.        ,   0.26726124],
       [  1.33630621,   1.22474487,   1.06904497]])
```

#### Pipelining

You can even use this pattern inside of a scikit-learn pipeline (and even persist it to disk):

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
pipe = Pipeline([
        ("scale", NanImputeScaler()),
        ("clf", LogisticRegression())
    ]).fit(data, y)
```